# Let $R$ be a finitely generated subring of a number field. Is $R/I$ finite for every non-zero ideal of $R$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, krull-dimension, finite-rings

Given *any* finitely generated subring $R$ of a number field (finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) or a global function field (finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$), does $R$ have the property that $R/I$ is a finite ring for every non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$?

It is sufficient to show that $R$ has Krull dimension $1$. Indeed, then $R/I$ is a finitely generated artinian ring, which is finite.

Comment: I don't have time to write a detailed answer, but the answer should be yes. For number fields the idea is to reduce to the case of rings of integers in number fields, where it suffices to show that a nonzero ideal $I$ contains a nonzero integer (e.g. using norms). The general case is a localization of a subring of a ring of integers. The function field case should be similar.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your comment. Can you sketch why the general case is a localization of a subring of a ring of integers? If that is true, I guess I can take it from there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458999/121097